# wcf data service linq query select into class webget data

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, wcf, class

Hey i have a problem with my wcf data service :
I use entity framework to webget my data as xml format into the webbrowser . This works fine. But when i want to put the data into a class and the perform the webget i get an error . I will show you my code below maybe somebody can help me ?

the webget:

```
[WebGet]
    public IQueryable<Wcolumns> GetAllCallers()
    {

        testCDREntities context = this.CurrentDataSource;

            var Callers = from table in context.TestTables
                          select new Wcolumns(){ CallerId = table.CallerId, SipCallId = table.SipCallId };

            return Callers.AsQueryable();



    }
```

And then the class :

```
namespace WcfApi
```

{

```
[DataServiceKey("SipCallId")]
public class Wcolumns
{
    public string CallerId { get; set; }

    public string SipCallId { get; set; }



}
```

}

I realy hope somebody can help me with this problem !

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What are the `Tables` in the `TestTables`? Are there more than one table in `TestTables`?

Comment: Yes that's the reason i only want a few tables because there are 60 tables in my table